# I am trying to write a simple smart contract in remix ide and getting encountered by a generic error again and again. Below is my code and error

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

Code:-

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

contract FundMe{

    mapping(address => uint256) public addressToAmountFunded;
    address public owner;

    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

     function fund() public payable {
        uint256 minimumUSD = 50 * 10 ** 18;
        require(getConversionRate(msg.value) >= minimumUSD, "You need to spend more ETH!");
        addressToAmountFunded[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    }

    function getVersion() public view returns (uint256){
        AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x8A753747A1Fa494EC906cE90E9f37563A8AF630e);
        return priceFeed.version();
    }
    
    function getPrice() public view returns(uint256){
        AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x8A753747A1Fa494EC906cE90E9f37563A8AF630e);
        (,int256 answer,,,) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
         // ETH/USD rate in 18 digit 
         return uint256(answer * 10000000000);
    }
    
    function getConversionRate(uint256 ethAmount) public view returns (uint256){
        uint256 ethPrice = getPrice();
        uint256 ethAmountInUsd = (ethPrice * ethAmount) / 1000000000000000000;
        // the actual ETH/USD conversation rate, after adjusting the extra 0s.
        return ethAmountInUsd;
    }

    function withdraw() payable public {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(address(this).balance);

    }

}
```

Error:-

Gas estimation failed
Close
Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
execution reverted

Basically when I am passing any Wei,gwei, or ether in my contract while deploying then I am getting this error otherwise it gets deployed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you deploy your contract, your `constructor` function is called, and it is not marked as payable.

```
constructor() payable {
    owner = msg.sender;
}
```

Make it payable and you are good

Comment: Hey @keser, I just did what you said and got the output, but I have a confusion here. If I am giving the input value of some wei before deploying then it is not allowing me to deploy the contract. However, by  deploying the contract first and then entering the same amount of wei gives me the desired output. Could you tell me why this is happening?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your confusion. When deploying your contract, you are calling your constructor function under the hood. Without the `payable` modifier, a function (in this case the constructor)  can not process transactions with value

Comment: I understood all about the constructor thing. I am just asking that that after we compile our program we have give the value as wei,gwei or ether, or we have to set its value after deploying the contract.

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding your question, maybe my head isn't in the right place sorry.

Comment: No problems,keser. I am just asking to set the value before deploying the contract or after deploying the contract.

Comment: Mmm doesn't really matter. I would do it while deploying though